# How to fix the error "no pg_hba.conf entry for host" from Heroku in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, heroku-postgres, nestjs-config

I configured TypeORM for Heroku using a guide and the `ormconfig.js` looks like this:

```
const dbConfig = {
    synchronize: false,
    migrations: ['migrations/*.js'],
    cli: {
      migrationsDir: 'migrations',
    },
};

switch(process.env.NODE_ENV){
    case 'development':
        Object.assign(dbConfig, {
            type: 'sqlite',
            database: 'db.sqlite',
            entities: ['**/*.entity.js'],
        });
        break;
    case 'test':
        Object.assign(dbConfig, {
            type: 'sqlite',
            database: 'test.sqlite',
            entities: ['**/*.entity.ts'],
            migrationsRun: true,
            ssl: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
        });
        break;
    case 'production':
        Object.assign(dbConfig, {
            type: 'postgres',
            url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
            migrationsRun: true,
            entities: ['**/*.entity.js'],
        });
        break;
    default:
         throw new Error('unknown environment')
    
}

module.exports = dbConfig;
```

I have also created a `Procfile` file in the project for Heroku with the command `web: npm run start:prod`.
I only have a few simple routes at the moment and locally I can run the api with SQLite without errors. But when I try to run the api on Heroku, I get this error:

```
2022-07-17T11:53:53.748981+00:00 app[web.1]: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", user "foofoofoof", database "foofoofoof", no encryption
2022-07-17T11:53:53.748981+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
2022-07-17T11:53:53.748982+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Parser.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
2022-07-17T11:53:53.748982+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
2022-07-17T11:53:53.748983+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
2022-07-17T11:53:53.748983+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
2022-07-17T11:53:53.748984+00:00 app[web.1]:     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
2022-07-17T11:53:53.748984+00:00 app[web.1]:     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
2022-07-17T11:53:53.748984+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
2022-07-17T11:53:53.748984+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
2022-07-17T11:53:53.879579+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-07-17T11:53:53.945790+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I configured my `app.module` using the same instructions for my database and it looks like this:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { IngredientsModule } from './ingredients/ingredients.module';
import { RecipesModule } from './recipes/recipes.module';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    UsersModule,
    IngredientsModule,
    RecipesModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

For Heroku, I created three environment variables `COOKIE_KEY`, `DATABASE_URL` (was created automatically), `NODE_ENV` under Config Vars:
[image]

My script section in `package.json` looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nest start",
    "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest",
    "test:watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --watch --maxWorkers=1",
    "test:cov": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json --maxWorkers=1",
    "typeorm": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
  },
```

How can I fix this error in NestJS or Heroku?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution how to get rid of this error.

Run in the console:

```
heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=no-verify
```